# Синтаксис Return в VBA

Tags: vba

Как получить возвращаемое значение функции?

Т.е. объявил функцию:

```
Public Function GetPi() As Double
    Return 4.0 * Math.Atan(1.0)
End Function
```

Жалуется на строку с Return и пишет Syntax error.

И как правильно (по синтаксису) принимать значение функции.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Google:VBA функции](https://www.google.ru/search?q=vba+functions&rlz=1C1LENN_enRU504RU504&aq=f&oq=vba+functions&aqs=chrome.0.57j0l3.4935j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&safe=off&rlz=1C1LENN_enRU504RU504&q=vba+%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8&revid=1397907763&sa=X&ei=LT9pUeDqBuaL4gTb44CwDQ&ved=0CKIBENUCKAE&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45175338,d.bGE&fp=364d6440e7471a0b&biw=1364&bih=640)
[Самая верхняя ссылка](http://on-line-teaching.com/vba/lsn0109.html)

```
Public Function GetPi() As Double
    GetPi = 4.0 * Math.Atan(1.0)
End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

в VBA для возврата значения надо присвоить что-то имени функции.

Answer (score 1):

Если возвратов несколько, то используется `Exit Function`

```
Public Function GetSomething() As Double
    If ... Then
        GetSomething = 0
        Exit Function
    End If

    ....

    GetSomething = 1
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Для большей универсальности можно передавать в функцию переменные:

```
Sub test1()
    MsgBox fGetPi(4, 0.9)
End Sub

Sub test2()
    Dim a As Long, b As Double

    a = 18: b = 0.2
    MsgBox Round(fGetPi(a, b), 3)
End Sub

Public Function fGetPi(lParameter1 As Long, dParameter2 As Double) As Double
    fGetPi = lParameter1 * Application.Atanh(dParameter2)
End Function
```

Если в функции вычисления сложнее, то правильнее не присваивать функции результат на каждом промежуточном этапе, а объявить дополнительную переменную:

```
Sub test_()
    MsgBox fSumIf("sum1", 12, 5, 8)
    MsgBox fSumIf("sum2", 3, 1, 0)
    MsgBox fSumIf("sum3", 5, 5, 5)
End Sub

Public Function fSumIf(sCondition As String, a As Long, b As Long, c As Long) As Long
    Dim lTemp As Long
    
    Select Case sCondition
    Case "sum1"
        lTemp = a + b: lTemp = lTemp + c
    Case "sum2"
        lTemp = b + c
    Case "sum3"
        lTemp = a * c: lTemp = lTemp + b
    End Select
    
    fSumIf = lTemp
End Function
```